# Get launch's URL using ReportPortal agent-java-testNG

Tags: reportportal

I want to print the launch URL to the console after the execution
is there a way to get that url?
I am using Java and TestNG.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such possibility right now. Please, add the issue to Github, team will add this to JVM client v4 which is supposed to be released soon.

Comment: @AviUlman please accept the answer from avarabyeu )) we have a online dashboard, and track those question in live mode. Now it blinks as Not_Answered

Answer (score 0):

This code works for ReportPortal 5.5.1 and `com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-junit5:5.1.5`

```
String uuid = System.getProperty("rp.launch.id");
LaunchResource l = ReportPortalExtension.REPORT_PORTAL.getClient().getLaunchByUuid(uuid).blockingGet();
String reportUrl = String.format("%s/report/ui/#%s/launches/all/%s",
    "<rp.endpoint>",
    "<rp.project>",
    l.getLaunchId());
```